# how change encoding after password migration to hybris

Tags: encoding, passwords, sap-commerce-cloud

I am migrating customer password which encoded with sha1. I write a custom encoder and successfully I can migrate. After migrating, I want that when customer changes their password, also changes the encoding to hybris default encoding, but still use the custom encoder. How can I handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extend **DefaultCustomerAccountService** **changePassword** method for setting new encoding. UserModel already has PasswordEncoding attribute. When **changePassword** method call by somewhere, check usermodel encoding and call setPassword method with new encoding. This method already set new encoding to usermodel.

If you are planning to use custom encoding you can develop your own with PasswordEncoder interface.