# How does hybris store password hashes

Tags: passwords, sap-commerce-cloud, password-hash, password-storage

**TLDR:** What does Hybris do with password hashes before storing them in the database? Because values in the database field are NOT standard password hashes.

---

I had to add the *TLDR* above, because two users posted answers that are indicative that they didn't read (or understand) the question.

I'm working with Hybris 1905.  When I set a user's password in backoffice, I can choose the type of hashing algorithm, including MD5, SHA-256 and a few others.  Yet the password value stored in the database is clearly not a simple hash with the algorithm.  For example, here are hashes of password `test1234`, with various hashing algorithms:

- Salted MD5: `1:Gtjd5QVM/t0HLT5PvZCU4g==s9B8Vw/BIkzixwzMzueRR1R6WY9y8Fq9BqFqwGIuY2fGK+KFYSXjNf5G0fbAlb9u`
- SHA-256: `1:etvHTnwzMfX/DnbNPhmQBA==8jq6sLLcb/PrIhVB9D+YA61L2mr0dlBYr/84G/K9Kzqe4gpvPF10ja8RaIE94b3A+joszlMutGrHezDs871A/8Yr4oVhJeM1/kbR9sCVv24=`
- SHA-512: `1:ZSaQW0C+r/NMVwRRVTCm9w==4qQJdmvU4PE02ipY0Mvkp2sb+bMuMHTiMIVE2m6NESzv2BEFG2O1MIjkzFUES6f7jzoVOEuVmd/E8mqOUoogbL9rpkOPmeMEj5EpB2iued3UAouLvv6PuUCyFJGJdoRsZJzwO2Lj30iokY4RsG0OKXYuGdUjNYU7X1AUggH+eWfGK+KFYSXjNf5G0fbAlb9u`
- PBKDF2 (HMAC−SHA1): `1:HIKWvUwTA/pVC9mXzl9qgw==NOsr8pkNUIbEGoiWFa5oArnlEfZNALK0cuczK7dxtxHbDTby+7w3ml1pf8HNmXjalq1A/tSvlb+gwZMRS4Q7ncMhU5w1b6HwV+BGEBG9ecqahzUOK7mNZrLbh9t50M0mRr2AVQJnn7bfvdJ5E3C4UPdoN44v1mAgIuC/9RKTnhj/1BhjHqKf1pozhFfoBz8FdSxBQMmKY91/c4VzkinqiSy5wkaWjOSQQuAN9ZoWmvw=`
- BCrypt: `1:GL1kPl93Nx4RjOymIhC1Kw==Xh9ZddGPIxUqpipcEvJ+bRHApEyWVPkXtxPlsYgzokUo4ktC/vh4weA6hrMEebtQC/OttaVzG3+9tUCHxFHCcw==`

Clearly this is some sort of encoding that Hybris puts on top of the chosen hashing algorithm - but what is it?  Is it encoding (i.e. can be decoded) or hashing?

I need to migrate a large database of users from another platform to this Hybris installation.  I have existing usernames and corresponding hashed passwords, which I want to import. These are standard bcrypt hashes, so the same `test1234` string would have hash `$2y$16$mK9cm.pwOp8ve9oH0VqkT.123HGy/RHYLcd1GB.N5zEqBylV.22wm`. Yet I am struggling to understand how to import this hash into Hybris users table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What does Hybris do with password hashes before storing them in the
> database? Because values in the database field are NOT standard
> password hashes.

Its because `encodedPassword` attribute declared with `encrypted="true"` modifier. Due to that hybris encrypt value before storing to DB. Read more about [Transparent Attribute Encryption (TAE)](https://help.sap.com/viewer/d0224eca81e249cb821f2cdf45a82ace/1905/en-US/8b2c75c886691014bc12b8b532a96f58.html) and how it works in hybris.

```
 <attribute autocreate="true" qualifier="encodedPassword" type="java.lang.String">
            <persistence type="property" qualifier="Passwd">
                <columntype>
                    <value>HYBRIS.LONG_STRING</value>
                </columntype>
            </persistence>
            <modifiers read="true" write="true" search="true" optional="true" encrypted="true"/>
        </attribute>
```

---

In your case, you probably need to create your own password encoder and set it to all migrated users, so that your system manages to authenticate migrated users with custom encoder, and then you can redirect the user to reset the password. In the reset password flow, you can update the password encoding with the new OOTB encoder so that new hash will be generated.

other references [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46373742/how-change-encoding-after-password-migration-to-hybris), [2](https://answers.sap.com/answers/12782421/view.html)

Comment: Ah! That would make sense.  I don't see why I would need to change encoders or have users reset their passwords.  I created a new encoder and added it into the system.  Now when I look at a user's record in backoffice, I can select my new encoder for password - so I should be able to just import users as is (using impex with `encodedPassword` field, I guess)

Comment: if you want to use your custom encoder throughout your project you do not need to force users to update passwords, but at later point, if you want to stick with OOTB provided encoder then you can redirect the user to reset the password and set a new password with the OOTB encoder.

Comment: Hybris allows different users to use different encoders.  There's actually an attribute on "Users" model, called "passwordEncoding".  So there's nothing wrong with keeping the custom encoder for the imported users, but using an OOTB one for new users or when passwords are reset later on.

Comment: yeah, I know. but I would suggest sticking with uniform encoder throughout all the users, which makes our life easy for further migration/up-gradation

Answer (score -1):

[Hybris always stores passwords in an *encoded format*](https://help.sap.com/viewer/9433604f14ac4ed98908c6d4e7d8c1cc/2005/en-US/dcb16eb922a24d5d92d9be72b52889e3.html?q=password). The default strategy in SAP Commerce is `PBKDF2`. When necessary, you can change it through the `default.password.encoding` property.
You can also [implement your own password encoding strategy](https://help.sap.com/viewer/d0224eca81e249cb821f2cdf45a82ace/2005/en-US/8c256c54866910149de4d53a72e973d4.html) by implementing the `PasswordEncoder` interface and [adding the custom password encoding strategy bean](https://help.sap.com/viewer/d0224eca81e249cb821f2cdf45a82ace/2005/en-US/8bf04db4866910149816b1fb7cc26cf0.html) to `core.passwordEncoderFactory` bean.

Comment: Thid has nothing to do with my question. Please read it again and you will hopefully understand what I am asking.

Answer (score -1):

to correct my answer, Hybris always create a hash with the combination of username and password.

--->PasswordEncoderFactoryImpl class is responsible to give correct Encoder class based on the input of encoding.
--->factory.getEncoder(encoding).encode(user.getUID(), password)

Hybris supports [image]

you can test with an already existing test user and knowing the password to generate a hash key based algo and match the encoded password, it should give results as same.

---> to validate it just write simple groovy and output of groovy you can compare with a test user used in groovy via back office and compare encoded password.
here encoding is **pbkdf2**
[image]

Comment: This had nothing to do with my question. I am asking what hybris does with the hash after it is created with the chosen algorithm. The stored hash is not an md5 or bcrypt, but something entirely different.

Comment: Further, passwords cannot be decrypted, they are one way hashed, so your suggestion is pointess

Comment: @AleksG, I have modified the answer, maybe this will help you to understand the creation of hash in Hybris.

Comment: I do understand the flow. What I want to know is _what hybris does AFTER the hash is created_, because the hash stored in the database is _not_ in the standard pbkdf2, bcrypt, md5, etc format.

Comment: Generated hash also get encrypted as per [Transparent Attribute Encryption](https://help.sap.com/viewer/d0224eca81e249cb821f2cdf45a82ace/1905/en-US/8b2c75c886691014bc12b8b532a96f58.html) so it's not as per standard generated hash